# Regex with global modifier to capture words within lines

Tags: regex, pcre

**The Input:**

Let's consider this string below

```
*     key     : foo bar        *
*     big key : bar*bar        
*     healthy : cereal bar     *
      sadly   : without star   *
```

**The Output:**

I would like to retrieve the key:value pairs for each match.

1. 'key', 'foo bar'
2. 'big key', 'bar*bar'
3. 'healthy', 'cereal bar'
4. 'sadly', 'without star'

**The Regex:**

My first success was achieved with this Regex (PCRE/Perl):

```
/(\n?)([^\* ].*[^ *])\s+:\s+([^\* ].*[^ *])[\s\*]+(?|\n)/g
```

Here the [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eL8gZ6/2).

**My question**

I really find my regex pretty ugly. The main reason is because I can't use `/^` and `$/` in a global regex and I had to play with `/(\n?)...(?|\n)/g`.

Is there any possibility to shorten the above regex ?

**The optional challenge**

Actually this was the easy part. My string is supposed to be embedded in a C comment and I have to make sure I am not trying to match something outside a comment block.

(I not really need an answer to this second tricky question because if I write a script I can first match all the comments blocks, then find all the key:values patterns).

```
/********************************
 *     key     : foo bar        *
 *     big key : bar*bar        
 *     healthy : /*cereal bar   *
       sadly   : without star   *
 ********************************/
       not a key : this key
```

Comment: your question is "is there any possibility to shorten the above regex". Am i correct?

Comment: Why can't you use `^` and `$` anchors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `m` -flag to the regexp to make anchors `^` and `$` match beginnings and ends of each line within the string, i.e:

```
/^\s*\*?\s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*\*?\s*$/gm
```

Note the use of non-greedy quantifiers (`+?` and `*?`) to not eat up characters that can be matched after the quantifier, i.e. the first capture group will not include the optional trailing whitespace before the colon, and the second capture group will not include trailing whitespace and an optional asterisk at the end of a line.

Comment: Good point too. I didn't know about non-greedy quantifiers. This is very useful in my example!

Comment: Here they're not needed, as the trailing whitespaces would be matched by the \s* (greedy operator) after the capture groups. But worth knowing them indeed. For what it worth I'm used to use `[meta-char]` notation instead of escaping them to be clear it is a litteral char inside the regex

Comment: @Tensibai, if you use greedy quantifiers inside the capture groups you will end up with whitespace within the capture. Yes, the whole expression will still match, but you get cleaner data in the capture.

Comment: @krisku Same comment as on the other answer. My bad I forgot \s will match newlines too

Answer (score 1):

http://regex101.com/r/oJ8uW4/1

the regex I used is: `/^\s*[*]*\s+(.*)\s+:\s+(.*?)\s+[*]*\s*$/gm`

It works for your exemple as the `not a key : this key` has no space after it, so it would miss comments which do not close whith `*` and get values with trailing spaces too.

The point you're looking for is the modifiers after the last /
`m` to says it's multiline so `^` and `$`  are usable and `g` to rematch on each line.

The drawback is you can't rely on having `/*` and `*/` on lines around when using `^` and `$`

But Avinash will prove me wrong I bet :) (he's far better than me with regexes)

Comment: Whah! I didn't know I can use `(?g)` and `(?m)` together. This is good

Comment: every modifier can be added, so `gmi` would do a global multiline case insensitive match

Comment: In the Perl Regex Tester http://retester.herokuapp.com/ `       sadly   : without star   *` returns `$2=> [without star * ]` instead of `without star`. This is also a case at the site linked in the question.

Comment: Thanks, didn't got it at first, we need a reluctant operator here in the second capture group. I update. That's quite strange as the `\s+` should be matched and consume at least one space after the capture group...

Comment: My bad, rechecked and the \s will match newline too, that's why the capture group takes it until the end of line.